# jQuery on event method doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I want to remove background of input element on input event(any character), but that doesn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#password").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#username").on("input", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "none");

  $("#password").on("input", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
```

Comment: `"#username` is an invalid string literal, it is missing the closing quotes `"`. You have multiple errors like this one.

Comment: I forgot to close it, but even with that doesn't trigger

Comment: Aside from the missing quotes; you aren't closing your function blocks

Comment: Also, I don't think `none` is a valid value for `background-color`, try `initial`.

Comment: 1) `none` is not a valid background color. Try `transparent` instead 2) don't nest your event handlers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't think they were intentionally nested. Just the `})` were omitted.

Comment: Good point. Reverted that part of my edit

Comment: 3) this would be better serviced with class manipulation rather than DOM styling

Answer (score 0):

`background-color:none` isn't valid css. Also your password event binding was inside your username one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#password").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#username").on("input", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
  });
 $("#password").on("input", function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors where you forgot to close the functions you passed to `on`. `none` is also not valid for `background-color`, using `initial` is probably what you wanted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#password").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#username").on("input", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "initial");
  });
  $("#password").on("input", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "initial");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
```